# How do I get into my virtualenv quicker? Custom commands?

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv

everytime I want to do something with terminal I have to type this sequence in the terminal (Im on mac osx lion terminal):

```
>Public/projects/installs # location of my venv 
>. venv/bin/activate # activates the venv within terminal
```

Is their anyway to do this faster or create a custom function/ command in the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
It allows you to switch virtualenvs by typing `workon <env_name>`. You create virtualenvs by `mkvirtualenv <env_name>` or `mkproject <project_name>` if you have set up a `PROJECT_HOME` and want the working directory there.

You can do a lot more than just switch venvs, though. For example you can set up hooks that are performed for every new venv (installing ipython if you want to, set up a .hgignore) and when activating one (e.g. setting the `PATH` if you have things installed via npm).

Comment: how do I make venv one of the environments in the wrapper?

Comment: an existing virtualenv? You could probably move it to `WORKON_HOME`, but I'd get a list of installed requirements via `pip freeze > requirements` and create a new one, installing with `pip install -r requirements`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (already described in two other answers), you might want to check out [`autoenv`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv). That lets you get into a venv just by doing a `cd` to its directory.

For fancy stuff, there are a lot of differences between the two projects, and I think `virtualenvwrapper` is generally more powerful and flexible. But for simple use cases like yours, the choice comes down to which of these you'd prefer:

```
$ workon projects_installs
```

… or

```
$ cd Public/projects/installs
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
It can be installed with `pip install virtualenvwrapper`, and requires setting up some lines in your .bashrc file. Then you get the `mkproject` and `workon` commands to make creating and switching virtualenvs much easier.